# Unable to fix the misaligned results

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to parse the value of some items from a dictionary and print them accordingly. I did parse them but when I tried to print them, the output becomes uglier considering the alignment. How can I get the printed result the way I've shown in expected output?

Items in the dictionary [curtailed portion]:

```
dict_items = [{'factLabel': 'Mode', 'factValue': 'Single'},
{'factLabel': 'Year', 'factValue': '1973'},
{'factLabel': 'Condition', 'factValue': 'Forced'},
{'factLabel': 'Identity', 'factValue': None},
{'factLabel': 'Availability', 'factValue': 'Rare'},
{'factLabel': 'Earn', 'factValue': 'Private'}]
```

I tried like the following to parse the value of different keys conditionally:

```
for elem in dict_items:
    mode = elem['factValue'] if elem['factLabel']=="Mode" else ""
    year = elem['factValue'] if elem['factLabel']=="Year" else ""
    condition = elem['factValue'] if elem['factLabel']=="Condition" else ""
    identity = elem['factValue'] if elem['factLabel']=="Identity" else ""
    availability = elem['factValue'] if elem['factLabel']=="Availability" else ""
    income = elem['factValue'] if elem['factLabel']=="Income" else ""
    print(mode,year,condition,identity,availability,income)
```

Result I'm getting:

```
Single     
 1973    
  Forced   
   None  
    Rare
```

Expected output:

```
Single 1973 Forced None Rare
```

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the data? Will it always be composed of these two-item key:value style dictionaries? Why are they dictionaries in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, particularly since you intend to output the data as CSV. The ideal solution will depend entirely on the specifics of your use case, more specifically, the format of your data.

I will update my solution if we receive more information on where the data comes from, and how you plan to use it,

---

```py
dict_items = [{'factLabel': 'Mode', 'factValue': 'Single'},
              {'factLabel': 'Year', 'factValue': '1973'},
              {'factLabel': 'Condition', 'factValue': 'Forced'},
              {'factLabel': 'Identity', 'factValue': None},
              {'factLabel': 'Availability', 'factValue': 'Rare'},
              {'factLabel': 'Earn', 'factValue': 'Private'}]

vals = dict(curr.values() for curr in dict_items)
```

`vals`:

```py
{'Mode': 'Single', 'Year': '1973', 'Condition': 'Forced', 'Identity': None, 'Availability': 'Rare', 'Earn': 'Private'}
```

---

```py
dict_items = [{'factLabel': 'Mode', 'factValue': 'Single'},
              {'factLabel': 'Year', 'factValue': '1973'},
              {'factLabel': 'Condition', 'factValue': 'Forced'},
              {'factLabel': 'Identity', 'factValue': None},
              {'factLabel': 'Availability', 'factValue': 'Rare'},
              {'factLabel': 'Earn', 'factValue': 'Private'}]

vals = {curr['factLabel']: curr['factValue'] for curr in dict_items}
```

`vals`:

```py
{'Mode': 'Single', 'Year': '1973', 'Condition': 'Forced', 'Identity': None, 'Availability': 'Rare', 'Earn': 'Private'}
```

Comment: No need to update. Your solution is already perfect. It's really embarrassing that I could not think myself either of the ways. Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt There’s no reason to be embarrassed! :) It’s up to you, I just felt like there was certainly a better solution. I was thinking of breaking out the namedtuples, too

Answer (score 0):

For your example to work, I advice you to study how does [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) work. The following change of `print` function works for me:

```
print('{}{}{}{}{}'.format(mode,year,condition,identity,availability,income), end=' ')
```

Comment: It will still lead me to the wrong alignment when I print the same in a csv file. I was after any solution to fix that, not any workaround. Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt The fact that you want to write these to a CSV file is relevant information, can you update your post with some more details?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on above python 3.6+ can use f strings:

```
print(f"{mode}{year}{condition}{identity}{availability}{income}", end=" ")
```